# Would like to perform transactions only when webView is completely loaded

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview

I would like to perform transactions only when webView is completely loaded.

I'm writing down the following code.

However, NSLog(@"completely loaded") is called several times.

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView*)webView
{
     self.webViewLoadingCount++;
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)webView
{
    self.webViewLoadingCount--;
    if (self.webViewLoadingCount > 0) {
         // loading
         return;
    }
    // completely loaded
    NSLog(@"completely loaded");

}
```

Could you tell me how to solve this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Do you ever initialize `self.webViewLoadingCount`?

Comment: Yes. I initialize self.webViewLoadingCount with zero.